# monitoring rtmpdump feeds using powershell and rtmpdump

Tags: powershell

I am trying to monitor live tv channels rtmp feed using powershell and rtmpdump. streams that i want to monitor saved in "streams.txt" file which follows following csv format.

```
Name,feed,file
tv1,rtmp://server/live/tv1,tv1.flv
tv2,rtmp://server/live/tv1,tv2.flv
tv3,rtmp://server/live/tv1,tv3.flv 
tv4,rtmp://server/live/tv1,tv4.flv
```

After importing csv file and converting data in objects I traverse each object and using the feed property i launch rmtpdump command once this process is working rest of the powershell is halted.

to solve that I try to use timer but even they are not solving my problem when rtmpdump is capturing first feed inside loop.

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier  thetimer -Action $action 



$colStats = Import-CSV streams.txt
foreach ($objBatter in $colStats)
  {
    $timer.start()
    $objBatter.feed  + "," + $objBatter.file
    .\rtmpdump.exe -r $objBatter.feed -o $objBatter.file

  }



#to stop run 
$timer.stop() 
#cleanup 
Unregister-Event thetimer

#loop through flv files and all 0 bytes files are faulty channel

#deleting files with 0 size
#dir | ? {$_.length -eq 0} | del
```

I need to capture output of the feed for 30 seconds playback and then kill the rtmpdump process and in next iteration of loop i want to capture 2nd feed for 30 seconds.

If one stream is not working it will genrate flv file of 0 byte that i later get to send notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cls;
Set-Location "C:\users\najam.sikander\Desktop\rtmpdump"
#deleting flv files
dir *.flv | del
get-process -name rtmp* | kill
<#
$timer = new-object timers.timer 

$action = {
write-host "Time to kill rtmp: $(get-date -Format ‘HH:mm:ss’)"
#get-process -name rtmp* | kill
} 


$timer.Interval = 30000 #3 seconds  

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier  thetimer -Action $action 

#>

$colStats = Import-CSV streams.txt
$files = (dir *.flv | measure).Count
Write-Host $files

While ($files -lt $colStats.Length)
{

$arguments = "-r " + $colStats[$files].feed + " -o " + $colStats[$files].file + " -m 20 -v"
Start-Process "C:\users\najam.sikander\Desktop\rtmpdump\rtmpdump.exe" $arguments   

do
{
    Write-Host $colStats[$files].feed
    Write-Host $colStats[$files].file
    $streaming = $true;

    $fileCh = (dir $colStats[$files].file | measure).Count

    Write-Host $files

    if($fileCh -gt 0)
    {
        while ((dir $colStats[$files].file).Length -lt 1000){
            $dump  = (get-process -name rtmp* | measure).Count
            if($dump -eq 0)
            {
                break
            }
        }
        $streaming = $false
        get-process -name rtmp* | kill
    }
}
while ( $streaming -eq $true)

$files = (dir *.flv | measure).Count
Write-Host $files
}


#getting working and not workign streams sets based on flv files
$working = dir *.flv | ? {$_.length -ge 1000} 
$notworking = dir *.flv | ? {$_.length -eq 0}  
Write-Host "working = " ($working |measure).Count
$working
Write-Host "not working = " ($notworking |measure).Count
$notworking

#deleting flv files
dir *.flv | del
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this does what you want... It will loop through the csv file, run the rempdump process for 30 seconds, kill it, and then go to the next feed.

```
#Import the streams
$colStats = Import-CSV streams.txt

#Loop through the streams
foreach ($objBatter in $colStats)
{
    $Process = ".\rtmpdump.exe"
    $arguments = "-r $objBatter.feed -o $objBatter.file"

    #Launch Process
    $Ps = Start-Process -FilePath $Process -ArgumentList $Arguments -PassThru

    #Wait 30 seconds
    Sleep -Seconds 30

    #Kill the process
    $Ps.Kill()
}

#loop through flv files and all 0 bytes files are faulty channel

#deleting files with 0 size
#dir | ? {$_.length -eq 0} | del
```

Comment: i have already tried the code you posted. sleep thing will not work cuz rtmpdump process will take to connect to remote server for feed. sleep process will just fire too soon and powershell will not do anything.